# Count number of short strings in a long string in R

Tags: r

suppose I have a long string such like:

```
c<-"abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba"
```

My question is how to quickly count the number of exact "abcd" in `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using library `stringr`, you can do it as follows (on larger set, it will be fairly fast and efficient):

```
library(stringr)
c <- "abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba"
c
[1] "abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba"

str_count(c, 'abcd')
[1] 4
```

This will work on a column of a data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(txt = rep(c, 10))
df$abcd_count <- str_count(df$txt, 'abcd')
df
                                 txt abcd_count
1  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
2  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
3  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
4  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
5  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
6  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
7  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
8  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
9  abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
10 abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba          4
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) gregexpr** First paste `"abcd"` onto `c` so that there is at least 1 match.  (This is needed because `gregexpr` returns -1 for any component of `c` having no matches rather than a zero length numeric vector.)  Now, `gregexpr` returns a list whose components are numeric vectors of the starting positions of the matches one component per component of `c` -- in this case `c` only has one component but the code below works more generally.  Now find the lengths of the components of the result of `gregexpr` and subtract 1 to take into account the extra `abcd` we added.  No packages are used.

**Example 1**

```
lengths(gregexpr("abcd", paste(c, "abcd"))) - 1
## [1] 4
```

**Note:** If we knew that there was at least one match it could be slightly simplified to: `lengths(gregexpr("abcd", c))` .

**Example 2**

Here is another example.  Here `DF` has 3 rows and the corresponding components of `c` have 4, 4, and 0 occurrences of `"abcd"`.

```
DF <- data.frame(c = c(c, c, "X")) # test input

lengths(gregexpr("abcd", paste(DF$c, "abcd"))) - 1
## [1] 4 4 0
```

**2) regmatches**

Here is an alternative approach.  This approach has the advantage that no special code is needed for the no-match case.  Again, no packages are used.

Here are the same two examples:

```
lengths(regmatches(c, gregexpr("abcd", c)))
## [1] 4

lengths(regmatches(DF$c, gregexpr("abcd", DF$c)))
## [1] 4 4 0
```

Comment: If you have a column of strings to match instead of a single character vector `c`, would this not require `apply` family function to compute the length per row?

Comment: This seems incorrect when there is no "abcd". The output will be 1 rather 0. stringr::str_count works.

Comment: @Gopata,  It works for a column too.  See 2nd example.

Comment: @David Z, Good point. Have fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using base Rs `gsub` and strsplit:

```
# example
temp <- "abcabcdabcdeabcdefghijkabcdabcaba"
# substitute pattern for character not in string, here 9
temp2 <- gsub("abcd", "9", temp)

# split on 9, and count number of elements
length(strsplit(temp2, split="9")[[1]]) - 1
```

You need the `[[1]]` because `strsplit` is designed to operate over vectors of strings, here the vector is of length 1. An alternative to [[1]] in this case is `unlist`.

Also, 1 is subtracted because the number of elements are one larger than the number of abcd patterns by 1.